# Iphone sdk - Get Localized text from specific localized.strings file

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, localized

Is it possible to get a localized string from a specific localized.strings file, rather than from the system chosen localized.strings file, ONLY ONE TIME. I do not need to change all the localized texts, only some of them.

What I want to do is to have localized strings defined from language preferences but also localization. So that a user from Brazil location with English lang will get the application in English but some texts will be specific to the region so I want them in Portuguese.

But a user from Argentina, also with iPhone in English will get the application in English but some texts will be in Spanish.

Something like

```
 NSLocalizedStringFromTable("string.key","pt_BR",nil)
```

I thought that sending that to the **table** parameter would work but it didn't as it looks for the name of the file and not for the language.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the different bundle to choosing specific language:

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pt-PT" ofType:@"lproj"];
NSBundle * bundle = nil;
if(path == nil){
    bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
}else{
    bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
}
NSString * str = [bundle localizedStringForKey:@"a string" value:@"comment" table:nil];
```

**Swift 3.0:**

```
extension Bundle {
    static let base: Bundle = {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Base", ofType: "lproj") {
            if let baseBundle = Bundle(path: path) {
                return baseBundle
            }
        }
        return Bundle.main
    }()
}

let localizedStr = Bundle.base.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: table)
```

Comment: This is brilliant – I don't know why it doesn't have more upvotes. Much easier than all the other suggested methods. I'm using it to get the version of a string in the development language, so I use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Base" ofType:@"lproj"];`

Comment: This is the top answer, I tested it and it works! Added Swift 3.0 version.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want to use NSBundle's `localizedStringForKey:value:table:` rather than `NSLocalizedString()`.  This method would give you the opportunity to specify a different table.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:@"stringKey" 
  value:defaultString table:tableName];
```

BTW, do not forget your `@` in front of objective-C strings ;-).

Comment: Yes I meant that, but the Table parameter is a .strings file name, so I need to have two additional files pt.strings and es.strings, rather than using the wanted Localizable.strings file. Not a problem to implement but does not answer my question though.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean `NSLocalizedStringFromTable`?

documented here:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_112

Comment: Yes I meant that, but the Table parameter is a .strings file name, so I need to have two additional files pt.strings and es.strings, rather than using the wanted Localizable.strings file.

Comment: Your question wasn't so clear then because it seemed to ask for how to get it from a different file. "Is it possible to get a localized string from a specific file, rather than from the predefined localized.strings file."